# Equivalent to Microsoft Forms 2.0 ComboBox .TopIndex property in Windows Forms and Access Forms?

Tags: winforms, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-forms, ms-forms

The (deprecated) Microsoft Forms 2.0 controls include a combobox which provides an invaluable property: .TopIndex ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/topindex-property)).

It seems that this property is not available with standard comboboxes in forms in Microsoft Access 2019 (according to the documentation), and is not available with standard comboboxes in Windows Forms (.NET) (here, ComboBox inherits from ListControl and does not provide this property, while ListBox also inherits from ListControl, but provides it).

I have a lot of old code which heavily relies on the .TopIndex property, and it's time to move that code to other technologies.

So I'd like to know if I have missed something in the documentation and if there is an equivalent property with another name which I could use to determine which items are visible in the list part of a combobox. I'd like to know this for comboboxes in Access 2019 (I am not that hostile towards this application as many others here are) as well as for comboboxes in Windows Forms.

I am aware that there are a lot of free and commercial controls (including comboboxes) with enhanced functionality for Windows Forms. I will definitely go that way (or write my own) unless I have missed something in the documentation.

However, the situation is completely different when it comes to Access 2019 forms. I could not find a single free third-party ActiveX / COM combobox which I could use on Access forms and which provides this functionality. Theoretically, I probably could write an ActiveX / COM control using .NET and then use it on Access 2019 forms, but this seems quite painful.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the use of TopIndex in a ComboBox (you may just need the SelectedIndex). You can have something similar (I think) if you want to show a specific item (`> MaxDropDownItems`), setting `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = N; comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`

Comment: In a ListBox, TopIndex (`LB_GETTOPINDEX`, `LB_SETTOPINDEX`) is used to recreate the previous layout when the LB's handle is recreated. In a ComboBox, it's dropdrown is always *new*.

Comment: Well, this property has proven extremely useful for implementing comboboxes with paging. I have an application where about 400.000 possible entries could get loaded into the combobox, which of course does not make any sense performance-wise and usability-wise. Therefore, I am starting with 50 entries and load the rest on demand. The problem here is that users could scroll the combobox dropdown with the mouse wheel as well as by PgUp, PgDown, Cursor etc.

Comment: You filter the `ComboBox.DataSource` for that (with LINQ or `DataTable.DefaultView` filters (+ LINQ, eventually))

Comment: Aren't these techniques for client-side filtering? Of course, I don't want to pull all possible records from the database and then filter them client-side. Furthermore, I can't imagine how a filter could help here. My problem is to determine what portion of the data I should fetch / show in the list part of the combobox, depending on the user's scrolling.

Comment: Are they? It depends. Are you using EntityFremework? Then no. Are you using SQL/StoredProcedure to fetch/paginate the data? Then no. A DataTable doesn't need to contain all the records from the DataBase, just a subset. But you didn't post any code related to the data access methods or the use of the TopIndex property and its logic. You could also get the DropDown when it's shown and `SendMessage` `LB_SETTOPINDEX` yourself. Hack-ish hard, probably. I never used that property myself, I don't think I miss it either.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful http://allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as .Net WinForm ComboBox goes, you have not missed anything as the functionality of the TopIndex property is not implemented.  That said, it is pretty straight forward to extend the base ComboBox control to add this property. The following example control should get you started.

This control attaches a listener to the native ListBox dropdown and updates the TopIndex property on WM_VSCROLL and the [LB_SETCARETINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-setcaretindex) (this captures the initial position on opening) messages.  Additionally, the base SelectedIndexChange event is used to capture changes due to keyboard actions (pgUp/pgDn, Arrow up/down).  The TopIndex property is retained after the dropdown closes and is reset on opening the dropdown. The control also exposes a TopIndexChanged event.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ComboBoxEx : Inherits ComboBox
  Private listBoxListener As ListBoxNativeWindow
  Public Event TopIndexChanged As EventHandler(Of ComboBoxTopIndexArg)

  Private _TopIndex As Int32 = -1

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New
    listBoxListener = New ListBoxNativeWindow(Me)
  End Sub

  Public Property TopIndex As Int32
    Get
      Return _TopIndex
    End Get
    Private Set(value As Int32)
      If value <> _TopIndex Then
        _TopIndex = value
        RaiseEvent TopIndexChanged(Me, New ComboBoxTopIndexArg(value))
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Protected Overrides Sub OnDropDown(e As EventArgs)
    _TopIndex = -1 ' reset on opening the listbox
    MyBase.OnDropDown(e)
  End Sub

  Private Class ListBoxNativeWindow : Inherits NativeWindow
    Private listBoxHandle As IntPtr
    Private TopIndex As Int32
    Private parent As ComboBoxEx

    Public Sub New(ByVal parent As ComboBoxEx)
      Me.parent = parent
      WireParent()
      If parent.IsHandleCreated Then
        GetListBoxHandle()
        AssignHandle(listBoxHandle)
      End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub WireParent()
      AddHandler parent.HandleCreated, AddressOf Me.OnHandleCreated
      AddHandler parent.HandleDestroyed, AddressOf Me.OnHandleDestroyed
      AddHandler parent.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf UpdateTopIndexOnIndexChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnHandleCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      GetListBoxHandle()
      AssignHandle(listBoxHandle)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnHandleDestroyed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      ReleaseHandle()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateTopIndexOnIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      SetParentTopIndex()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetListBoxHandle()
      Const CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO As Int32 = &H164
      Dim info As New ComboBoxInfo
      info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info)
      Dim res As Boolean = SendMessage(Me.parent.Handle, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, Nothing, info)
      listBoxHandle = info.hwndList
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
      Const WM_VSCROLL As Int32 = &H115
      Const LB_SETCARETINDEX As Int32 = &H19E

      MyBase.WndProc(m)
      If m.Msg = WM_VSCROLL OrElse m.Msg = LB_SETCARETINDEX Then
        SetParentTopIndex()
      End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetParentTopIndex()
      Const LB_GETTOPINDEX As Int32 = &H18E
      parent.TopIndex = SendMessage(listBoxHandle, LB_GETTOPINDEX, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub
  End Class

  Public Class ComboBoxTopIndexArg : Inherits EventArgs
    Public Sub New(topIndex As Int32)
      Me.TopIndex = topIndex
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property TopIndex As Int32
  End Class

#Region "NativeMethods"
  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
  Private Structure ComboBoxInfo
    Public cbSize As Int32
    Public rcItem As RECT
    Public rcButton As RECT
    Public stateButton As IntPtr
    Public hwndCombo As IntPtr
    Public hwndEdit As IntPtr
    Public hwndList As IntPtr
  End Structure

  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
  Private Structure RECT
    Public Left, Top, Right, Bottom As Int32
  End Structure

  <DllImport("user32.dll")>
  Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Int32, wParam As IntPtr, <Out()> ByRef lParam As ComboBoxInfo) As Boolean
  End Function

  <DllImport("user32.dll")>
  Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Int32, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Int32
  End Function
#End Region

End Class
```

I leave it to you to wrap this in an ActiveX exposed wrapper for use in Access.  Doing so is fairly easy using the templates in the [Microsoft InteropForms Toolkit 2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3264).  Just note that those templates are setup using the "Any CPU" platform and you will need to change that to "x86".

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I think there's nothing to add to this answer - absolutely great job! A few lines of code showing how to catch *any* event, plus a reference to a valuable toolkit which I wasn't aware of until now (have used .NET only a few times and had to put .NET code into an ActiveX only one time where I did it without the help of toolkits). If I could, I'd upvote this a hundred times.